# How can I mount a windows 7 partition from Ubuntu (with no knowledge of what I'm doing)?

Tags: partitioning, mount

I have no idea what I'm doing here, at all. I bought a lenovo laptop from a pawn store, and it had Windows 7 with a single locked user account. I'd like to access the current files without resetting the entire system, so I installed Ubuntu to a flash drive and have successfully booted from it (I'm using it now). However, I tried to access the Windows 7 files, and I apparently cannot mount the partition. I've done a lot of searching on this topic around the forums and FAQs and such, but most of what all is said makes no sense to me.

Can anyone explain, in layman's terms, how I can "mount" the Windows 7 "partition" (which I think is what I need to do)?

Comment: Two thoughts come to mind, if you bought it from a pawn shop, it would do a hard system restore(reset to factory settings) as you don't know what kind of settings the prior owner might have screwed up or what kind of viruses he may have downloaded. That is assuming you want to keep Windows as you question implies. I would encourage you to give Ubuntu a try, I have not looked back since I did and bought a brand new computer last year and completely wiped Windows 7 to Install Ubuntu. My second thought is that if the account is encrypted it may not be possible to acces at all...

Comment: Before you continue: Think carefully what you are doing. You might be accessing private files of the previous owner, breaching that persons privacy.
Ok, now to your issue: Windows uses NTFS, which should be supported out of the box under Ubuntu. So simply go to the file manager and select the Windows HDD from the list on the left. If that does not work, post the error message here, so we might have a clue why it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

in the better scenario you have to do what follow:

if you open the file manager, you can see an hard disk ico on the column in the left.
click it!

if you didn't see any column on the left (in the file manager), just click F9 button (mayby the thenth button of your keyboard)

In the best scenario you have to delete the win7 partition and install ubuntu!! ;)